# Getting seRious about time series with R

Tags: r, time-series

If you think back, to when you first started with time series analysis. What tools, R packages and internet resources do you wish you had known about?

What I'm trying to ask is, where should one start? Specifically, are there any resources for R that really boil it down for one who is "new" to time series analysis with R.

Comment: When I first started with time series analysis, there was no such thing as html or web browsers. R didn't exist. S-Plus didn't exist. "New S" didn't exist.  (Old S existed, but I didn't know about it.) It would seem odd to wish for specific resources to exist for platforms that didn't exist. What use for an R package without R, or a nifty web page without a world wide web for it to be on?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a [Time Series Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) that aims to summarize all the time series packages for R. It highlights some core packages that provide some essential functionality.

I would also recommend the book by [Shumway and Stoffer](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/) and the associated website, although it is not so good for forecasting.

My blog post on ["Econometrics and R"](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/econometrics-and-r/) provides a few other references that are useful.

Then there is my own book on forecasting using R: [Forecasting principles and practice](http://www.otexts.org/fpp).

Answer (score 13):

I've found the UseR! series book [Introductory Time Series with R](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-88697-8) by Cowpertwait and Metcalfe very useful in translating my time series statistics textbooks into R-speak.

Comment: I second that.  There's a lot of little gems in this book.

Answer (score 6):

For ecologists, [Tree diversity analysis](http://www.worldagroforestry.org/units/library/books/PDFs/Kindt%20b2005.pdf) can be a first healthy step into the right direction. The book is free, it comes with an R package ([BiodiversityR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiodiversityR/index.html)) and gives you a taste of other eco-packages (like vegan).

Comment: could you point out where the book discusses time series? I just searched through it and could not find the topic covered.